# Google Cloud expose application after SSH

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh-tunnel

I have a web application running on a private server. I use ssh port tunnelling to map the private server port's to that of google cloud VM port 8080, and when I do
`curl http://localhost:8080`
on gcp VM shell, it returns a valid response. However, when I try to access it from outside (in browser) using the external IP (or do `curl http://[external_IP]:8080` in shell), it returns "the IP refused to connect".

My firewall settings allow tcp traffic on 8080 s.t. when I run another application on port 8080 directly in VM without ssh (say a docker hello-world app) it is accessible from outside using the same link and works well. Is there additional configuration i must do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if your application is binding to **127.0.0.1** or **localhost**. If yes, change to **0.0.0.0**.

To accept traffic from the VPC requires binding to a network interface connected to the VPC. The address **0.0.0.0** means bind to all network interfaces.

The network **127.x.x.x** aka localhost or loopback address is an internal-only ([Class A](https://www.iitk.ac.in/LDP/LDP/nag2/x-087-2-issues.ip-addresses.html)) network. If your application only binds to the internal network, external applications cannot connect to your application.

If instead your goal is to bind to **localhost** and use SSH port forwarding to access the loopback address, then start SSH like this:

```
ssh -L 8080:127.0.0.1:8080 IP_ADDRESS_OF_VM
```

You can then access port 8080 on the VM this way:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8080
```

The curl command is connecting to port 8080 on your local machine. SSH then forwards that connect to port 8080 on the remote machine.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works. How very silly of me to not notice missing 0.0.0.0